# How to stop Dart's .forEach()?

Tags: dart

```dart
List data = [1, 2, 3];
data.forEach((value) {
  if (value == 2) {
    // how to stop?
  }
  print(value);
});
```

I tried `return false;` which works in jQuery, but it does not work in Dart.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  What does it actually do?

Comment: When you say this works in JavaScript, do you mean in a library like jQuery? I ask because it looks like the algorithm outlined here does not break on a return value of false: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Consider filing a bug if you want this feature.

Comment: Yes. You're right. It's about jQuery.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can also use a for/in, which implicitly uses the iterator aptly demonstrated in the other answer:

```dart
List data = [1,2,3];

for(final i in data){
  print('$i');
  if (i == 2){
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: the "takeWhile()" solution below takes advantage of more recent changes to Dart and is probably a better solution, for most cases.

Answer (score 49):

It is also possible to implement your example using forEach() and takeWhile().

```dart
var data = [1, 2, 3];
data.takeWhile((val) => val != 2).forEach(print);
```

Comment: .takeWhile() wasn't around when I posted the original answer.  I'd say it's now a more appropriate and elegant approach for most cases.

Comment: Looks like the list will get iterated twice. Could affect performance in case of big data.

Comment: takeWhile() returns a lazy Iterable, so there is only one iteration. But there will be some extra function call overhead compared to writing a for loop. The JIT may optimise some of this away. See the guts of the implementation in TakeWhileIterator.moveNext(): https://github.com/dart-archive/dev_compiler/blob/master/tool/input_sdk/lib/internal/iterable.dart#L565

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/a75ffc89566a1353fb1a0f0c30eb805cc2e8d34c/sdk/lib/internal/iterable.dart#L567

Answer (score 24):

Breaking a `List`

```dart
List<int> example = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

for (int value in example) {
  if (value == 2) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Breaking a `Map`

If you're dealing with a `Map` you can't simply get an iterator from the given map, but you can still use a `for` by applying it to either the values or the keys. Since you sometimes might need the combination of both keys and values, here's an example:

```dart
Map<String, int> example = { 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3 };

for (String key in example.keys) {
  if (example[key] == 2 && key == 'B') {
    break;
  }
}
```

Note that a Map doesn't necessarily have they keys as `[ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]` use a LinkedHashMap if you want that. If you just want the values, just do `example.values` instead of `example.keys`.

Alternatively if you're only searching for an element, you can simplify everything to:

```dart
List<int> example = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
int matched = example.firstMatching((e) => e == 2, orElse: () => null);
```

Answer (score 16):

The callback that forEach takes returns void so there is no mechanism to stop iteration.

In this case you should be using iterators:

```dart
void listIteration() {
  List data = [1,2,3];

  Iterator i = data.iterator;

  while (i.moveNext()) {
    var e = i.current;
    print('$e');
    if (e == 2) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Dart does not support non-local returns, so returning from a callback won't break the loop.
The reason it works in jQuery is that each() checks the value returned by the callback.
Dart forEach callback returns void.

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each

Answer (score 3):

based on Greg Lowe post, I used where for my project and also it works.

```
var data = [1, 2, 3];
data.where((val) => val != 2).forEach(print);
```

Comment: No, it won't work. It will remove values == 2 only, and forEach will go through values before and also after removed value.

Comment: but it works you can check data after this line by print(data ) and you will see the result is [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 1):

**Using Multiple Loop**

**Break Outer Loop**

```
OUTER: for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
    if (m[i][j] < 0) {
      print("Negative value found at $i,$j: ${m[i][j]}");
      break OUTER;
    }
  }
}
```

**Continue Outer Loop**

```
  outer: for (var v in a) {
    for (var w in b) {
      if (w == v) continue outer;
    }
    print(v);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full sample by **for-in** loop, that close to **forEach** style.

```
void main(){
  var myList = [12, 18, 24, 63, 84,99];

  myList.forEach((element) {
   print(element);
   if (element ==24); //break; // does not work
  });

 for(var element in myList) {
    print(element);
    if (element==24) break;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody suggest `where()` but it is not a general replacement for `forEach()` with break capability

(`where` is however a correct replacement for the use case showed in the example of the question. I, on the other hand, focus on the question in the title)

The functionality of `foreach()` but with an equivalent of `break`, is given by **`any()`**: to continue the loop you return false, to stop you return true; the result of any() can be ignored. I think it is more similar to `each()` in jquery (but in dart to stop you return true).

To have a loop with the index, but also the possibility in case of break the loop, I use the following extension:

```dart
extension IterableUtils<E> on Iterable<E> {

  /**
    Similar to Iterable.forEach() but:
    - with an index argument
    - with the optional capacity to break the loop, returning false
      Note: as for the return clause, you can omit it, as with forEach()
   */
  void forEachIndexed(Function(E element, int index) f) {
    int index = 0;
    for (E element in this) {
      if (f(element, index) == false) break;
      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Example:

```dart
void main() {

  List list = ["a", "b", "c"];

  list.forEachIndexed((element, index) {
    print("$index: $element");

    //Optional:
    if (element == "b") return false; //break
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN empty return from a forEach to break the loop;

```
List<int> data = [1, 2, 3];
int _valueToBePrinted; 

data.forEach((value) {
  if (value == 2) {
    _valueToBePrinted = value;
    return;
  }
});
// you can return something here to
// return _valueToBePrinted;
print(value);
```

anyway you shouldn't...

the catch is, you can't return anything in the entire forEach loop

```
//This don't work
data.forEach((value) {
  if (value == 2) {
    _valueToBePrinted = value;
    return;
  }
  if (value == 1) {
   return value;
  }
});
```