# How to return from a forEach loop in Dart?

Tags: for-loop, dart

I have this function

```
  bool nameExists(players, player) {
    players.forEach((f) {
      if (f.data['name'].toLowerCase() == player.toLowerCase()) {
        return true;
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
```

It always return false, even if the condition is satisfied.

Any ideas?

Comment: use `map` instead of `foreach`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There is no way to return a value from `forEach`.
Just use a `for` loop instead.

```
  bool nameExists(players, player) {
    for(var f in players) {
      if (f.data['name'].toLowerCase() == player.toLowerCase()) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: On top of that, the Dart style guide specifically [recommends](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal) using a `for` loop over a `forEach` unless you can reuse an existing function.

Comment: What about this statement "Dart does not support non-local returns, so returning from a callback won't break the loop"?? Is this old news and no longer applicable?  Or only applicable to the foreach loop?

Comment: Sure, but breaking the loop and returning a value seems to be the requirement in the question.

Answer (score 13):

For this specific use case, you can also use `any()` instead of `forEach()`, e.g.

```
bool nameExists(players, player) =>
  players.any((f) => f.data["name"].toLowerCase() == player.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this other SO:

[How to stop Dart's .forEach()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586995/how-to-stop-darts-foreach)

In it one of the responses says this:

> Dart does not support non-local returns, so returning from a callback won't break the loop. The reason it works in jQuery is that each() checks the value returned by the callback. Dart forEach callback returns void.

I have not located official documentation for this to provide a link.  But it makes sense based on similar questions, their answers, and the behavior of your code.

Also based on the other answers in that link you need to do this:
Note it uses a "for in" loop rather than foreach.  for in functions as a foreach in C# or similar languages function.

```
bool nameExists(players, player) {
  bool result = false;
  for(var f in players) {
    if (f.data['name'].toLowerCase() == player.toLowerCase()) {
      result = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Or there are examples of other mechanisms that can be used to achieve the same goal in the linked SO.

Comment: The examples you copied from do not use `forEach`. Instead they use a `for` or `while` loop. The `break` in the example code here is not syntactically allowed.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you're saying.  They actually changed the foreach to a for loop.  Interesting to know you cannot even use the break command for foreach.  I have updated the answer