# How to stop/break forEach loop in dart /flutter?

Tags: loops, flutter, dart, foreach

I want to break the forEach loop after the for loop execution is done.

```
  void main() {
      var id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];


      id.asMap().forEach((index, number) {
        print('ForEach loop');

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          print("for loop");
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: You can't use for instead . Dart won't allow it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return from a forEach loop in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336082/how-to-return-from-a-foreach-loop-in-dart)

Comment: No that's not working for me

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Can't break `forEach` with Dart.

You can use `for` and `indexOf`

```
  for (var number in id) {
    var index = id.indexOf(number);

    print('Origin forEach loop');

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      print("for loop");
    }

    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

I thought this will be helpful for you. using the label to break the loops.

```
 void main() { 
 outerloop: // This is the label name 

   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   print("Innerloop: ${i}"); 
   innerloop: 

  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) { 
     if (j > 3 ) break ; 

     // Quit the innermost loop 
     if (i == 2) break innerloop; 

     // Do the same thing 
     if (i == 4) break outerloop; 

     // Quit the outer loop 
     print("Innerloop: ${j}"); 
   } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: I want to break forEach loop not the for  loop.

Comment: @GaganSailor, use for for the usecase you wanted to use... basically does the same thing... idk about performance

Answer (score 6):

i don't think, you can stop `foreach`

use `for:`

```
var id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  for (int i in id) {
    if(i == 2)
      break;

    print('$i');
  }
```

Comment: Is there any way where we can bypass the ForEach loop??

Answer (score 4):

According to your scenario, I think this should work ,

```
for(int i = 0; i < id.asMap().length; i++){
  if(id.asMap()[i] == 4) //your condition
  {
     break;
  }
  // your for loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of breaking set a boolean to track when to run body of foreach or when not

```
void main() {
      var id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      bool forEachDone=false;

      id.asMap().forEach((index, number) {
        //forEachDone=false;
        print('ForEach loop');
       if(!forEachDone){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++,forEachDone=true) {
          print("for loop");
        }

       }
      });
    }
```

Comment: This will not break the ForEach loop.

Comment: you can't break but you can stop execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the index, a more performant method than using indexOf inside a for loop (which increases BigO complexity) would be to use a while loop based on index. Such as:

```
int index = 0;
while(index < someList.length) {
   if (<some test>) {
     break;
   }
   index++;
}
```