# How to do forEach in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter. I want to do for each to check my array JSON. I know typescript is doing like this:

```
Object.keys(res).forEach(key => {

 if (res[key].name === 'Max') {
   match = true;
 }

});

if (match) {
  console.log ('Username has been taken');
} else {
 console.log('Username is available');
}
```

My question is for **dart** language in Flutter, how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586995/how-to-stop-darts-foreach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Dart's .forEach()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586995/how-to-stop-darts-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 var decodedData= json.decode(response.body);
  for (var item in decodedDat){
   if(item['name'] == 'Max'){
    // if true
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find the below sample code for forEach in dart, which can used in flutter also.

```html
main() {
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    list.add('apple');
    list.add('ball');
    list.add('cat');
    list.forEach((element) => print(element));

    Set<String> set = Set.from(list);
    set.forEach((element) => print(element));    
}
```

Comment: Tks bro, `list.forEach((element) { } );` is true :D

Answer (score 1):

The Darty way to test whether an `Iterable` (and by extension `List`) contains an element that matches a predicate is with `any`.

```
bool match = list.any((s) => s == 'Max');
```