# How top stop looping through data snapshot from firebase in a flutter app when condition met

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Am getting data from `firebase` in my `flutter` app and I want to stop the `forEach` when a specific condition is met, here is my attend :

```dart
    await dbRef.child('station').once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) async {
      dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value) async {
        if (value['station_name'] == stationName){
          station = Station(
              stationName: value['station_name'],
              key: key,
              cityName: value['city_name'],
              stationLatitude: value['station_latitude'],
              stationLongitude: value['station_longitude']);
        }
        break;
      });
    }).catchError((e){
      print(e);
    });
```

the `break` statement is not working with `forEach` loop and I can't find a way to loop through the data using normal `for loop`  ..!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for` instead of `forEach`, Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587609/10498374)